# Reset Angular 7 Reactive From Validation

Tags: angular, validation, reset

I am using an Angular Reactive form as a search form. I want to be able to reset the form. I did this with the following code:

```
<button type="reset" (click)="onReset()">
    Reset
</button>
```

The reset method does the following:

```
onReset(){
    this.myForm.reset();
    this.myForm.markAsPristine();
    this.myForm.markAsUntouched();
}
```

This makes all the form controls empty. But it does not reset the form validation. I deactivate the submit button if the form is not valid. This works when I first use the form. After I click on reset the validation does not work anymore. It seems to be deaktivated after submitting the form.

How can I solve this? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that your form is invalid after you reset?

Comment: The validation checks if the form is empty. If it is empty the form is not valid and the  form submit button will be disabled. After I reset the form the form submit button will not be disabled if the form is empty. Therefore I could submit an empty form after resetting the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove validations on specific formGroup/formcontrol by using **clearValidators()**
for reactive forms.

```
 this.formGroup.clearValidators() or      
 this.formGroup.controls.controlName.clearValidators()
```

After this, you have to update form control with the removed validator

```
this.formGroup.controls.controlName.updateValueAndValidity()
```

This helped me to resolve same issue, hope it helps you to

Comment: This seems to work, but there is one little thing that does not work. I am using this code on my submit form: [disabled]="!myForm.valid" 
After I click on reset the button is still visible. Only when I change something in the form this will be not visible. It seems like the validation is not fired when pressing reset. Can I somehow trigger the validation manually when clicking on reset so that the button is not visible after clicking reset?

Comment: What is happening here is, your form is valid when you removed validators. So you require something to handle the button's disable view.

Comment: This solution is not working for >12 and so, if you are looking for a proper way to get it "solved" you will consider reading this thread https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190#issuecomment-305222426

Answer (score 9):

Please use the following code:

```js
this.myForm.reset()
Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach(key => {
  this.myForm.controls[key].setErrors(null)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party here the thing that worked for me was patch value. Which resets the validator control that was turning my inputs red.

```
this.formgroup.patchValue({ formControlName: [null, Validators.required] });
```

Hope this help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem of wanting to change the validation type of the form on the fly. A combination like the one below works quite well for me and I get rid of various problems in the app view:

```
onChange(event: any) {
   this.valForm.controls.controlName.setErrors(null);
   this.valForm.controls.controlName.clearValidators();
   if (conditionA) {
       this.valForm.get('controlName').setValidators([Validators.required, this.patternA]);
       this.valForm.controls.controlName.updateValueAndValidity();
   } else {
       this.valForm.get('controlName').setValidators([Validators.required, this.patternB]);
       this.valForm.controls.controlName.updateValueAndValidity();
   }
}
```

I hope it is as useful to you as it is to me!